# yamlbeans configuration to set privateFields

Tags: java, yaml, yamlbeans, audit4j

I need to configure how yamlbeans processes classes.
I want to set privateFields to true to non-transient fields will be used.
What do I need for this? Which file should I create and what to place in it?
I use Java and audit4j and I want to specify option `db_datasourceClass` but this option is private and can't be set through `audit4j.conf.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

db_datasourceClass option is getting using a [setter](https://github.com/audit4j/audit4j-db/blob/master/src/main/java/org/audit4j/handler/db/DatabaseAuditHandler.java#L535) method in the DB Handler.

You can simply set this option using follwing setting in yaml file.

```
- !org.audit4j.handler.db.DatabaseAuditHandler
   db_datasourceClass: <your datasource class>
```

You can place this configuration file in your classpath.